Filtrar los valores de un Array Object dentro de otro Array
Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es poder filtrar los valores de la propiedad "Precio" del objeto que está dentro de un Array, que a su vez está dentro de un Array Padre.
Estoy practicando con los Array Methods de Javascript, y estaba intentando hacer esto pero no logro conseguir cómo.
Les adjunto el código para que se den una idea.


const monitores = [
    { nombre: 'Monitor Samsung 24"', precio: 1199 },
    { nombre: 'Monitor Curvo HP 27"', precio: 2199 },
    { nombre: 'Monitor Portatil Lenovo Think 15.6"', precio: 2999 },
    { nombre: 'Monitor Samsung Smart Full HD 4K 32"', precio: 6499 },
];

const teclados = [
    { nombre: 'Teclado Razer Ornata V3 X Alambrico de Membrana', precio: 499 },
    { nombre: 'Teclado HyperX Alloy Core RGB Gaming Alambrico', precio: 459 },
    { nombre: 'Teclado inalámbrico USB 850 (Color Negro)', precio: 249 },
    { nombre: 'Teclado Primus Darth Vader Ballista90T Alambrico', precio: 500 },
];

const mouses = [
    { nombre: 'Mouse Inalambrico Logitech M170 con Receptor USB', precio: 109 },
    { nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme KMW-375BK Lightflex Inalambrico Plegable', precio: 119 },
    { nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme Vector Óptico Inalámbrico con 6 botones', precio: 79 },
    { nombre: 'Mouse Gamer Corsair M65 RGB Elite Tunable FPS Negro CH-93099011', precio: 450 },
];

const servidores = [
    { nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge T150 Procesador Intel Xeon E-2300 3.1Ghz 16GB de RAM ECC DDR4 1 TB HDD', precio: 9274 },
    { nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge R450 Silver 4314 2.4Ghz 16GB DDR4-ECC 2TB PROSUPPPORTMISSION SIN DVD', precio: 39032 },
    { nombre: 'Windows Server Standard 2022 64 bits Español DVD 16Core P73-08338', precio: 7412 },
    { nombre: 'Switch Intellinet 561068 de 16 puertos 10/100/1000 Rackmount', precio: 635 },
];

const electronicosTotales = [monitores, teclados, mouses, servidores];

electronicosTotales.filter( electronicFiltered => console.log(electronicosTotales.forEach( electronico => electronico.forEach( electronicPrice => electronicPrice.precio))))




No entiendo la pregunta, cual es la condición de filtrado, por ejemplo "los elementos con precio mayor a 1000", o "los elementos con precios pares", cualquier cosa, pero para filtrar debe existir una condición que no específicas

Según podrás ver en la documentación, filter() necesita una condición, en este caso < 500. Por tanto, tienes que recorrer los elementos y aplicar el filtro dentro del bucle.
Nota: Como podrás observar en los resultados, la comparación no incluye el valor 500. Si quieres esos valores, debes usar <= en la comparación.


const monitores = [{
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung 24"',
    precio: 1199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Curvo HP 27"',
    precio: 2199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Portatil Lenovo Think 15.6"',
    precio: 2999
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung Smart Full HD 4K 32"',
    precio: 6499
  },
];

const teclados = [{
    nombre: 'Teclado Razer Ornata V3 X Alambrico de Membrana',
    precio: 499
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado HyperX Alloy Core RGB Gaming Alambrico',
    precio: 459
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado inalámbrico USB 850 (Color Negro)',
    precio: 249
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado Primus Darth Vader Ballista90T Alambrico',
    precio: 500
  },
];

const mouses = [{
    nombre: 'Mouse Inalambrico Logitech M170 con Receptor USB',
    precio: 109
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme KMW-375BK Lightflex Inalambrico Plegable',
    precio: 119
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme Vector Óptico Inalámbrico con 6 botones',
    precio: 79
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Gamer Corsair M65 RGB Elite Tunable FPS Negro CH-93099011',
    precio: 450
  },
];

const servidores = [{
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge T150 Procesador Intel Xeon E-2300 3.1Ghz 16GB de RAM ECC DDR4 1 TB HDD',
    precio: 9274
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge R450 Silver 4314 2.4Ghz 16GB DDR4-ECC 2TB PROSUPPPORTMISSION SIN DVD',
    precio: 39032
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Windows Server Standard 2022 64 bits Español DVD 16Core P73-08338',
    precio: 7412
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Switch Intellinet 561068 de 16 puertos 10/100/1000 Rackmount',
    precio: 635
  },
];

const electronicosTotales = [monitores, teclados, mouses, servidores];

electronicosTotales.forEach(items => {
  console.log(items.filter((e) => e.precio < 500))
});



Si te interesa guardarlos en un objeto aparte, puedes usar find() junto con some(), por ejemplo:


const monitores = [{
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung 24"',
    precio: 1199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Curvo HP 27"',
    precio: 2199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Portatil Lenovo Think 15.6"',
    precio: 2999
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung Smart Full HD 4K 32"',
    precio: 6499
  },
];

const teclados = [{
    nombre: 'Teclado Razer Ornata V3 X Alambrico de Membrana',
    precio: 499
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado HyperX Alloy Core RGB Gaming Alambrico',
    precio: 459
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado inalámbrico USB 850 (Color Negro)',
    precio: 249
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado Primus Darth Vader Ballista90T Alambrico',
    precio: 500
  },
];

const mouses = [{
    nombre: 'Mouse Inalambrico Logitech M170 con Receptor USB',
    precio: 109
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme KMW-375BK Lightflex Inalambrico Plegable',
    precio: 119
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme Vector Óptico Inalámbrico con 6 botones',
    precio: 79
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Gamer Corsair M65 RGB Elite Tunable FPS Negro CH-93099011',
    precio: 450
  },
];

const servidores = [{
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge T150 Procesador Intel Xeon E-2300 3.1Ghz 16GB de RAM ECC DDR4 1 TB HDD',
    precio: 9274
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge R450 Silver 4314 2.4Ghz 16GB DDR4-ECC 2TB PROSUPPPORTMISSION SIN DVD',
    precio: 39032
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Windows Server Standard 2022 64 bits Español DVD 16Core P73-08338',
    precio: 7412
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Switch Intellinet 561068 de 16 puertos 10/100/1000 Rackmount',
    precio: 635
  },
];

const electronicosTotales = [monitores, teclados, mouses, servidores];


const dataFilter = electronicosTotales
  .filter(items =>
    items.some(item => item.precio < 500)
  )

console.log(dataFilter);




@deprecated
Para obtener los precios de todos los elementos, puedes usar map(). Ten en cuenta que los objetos están anidados, por eso, debes aplicar map dos veces.
Por ejemplo:


const monitores = [{
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung 24"',
    precio: 1199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Curvo HP 27"',
    precio: 2199
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Portatil Lenovo Think 15.6"',
    precio: 2999
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Monitor Samsung Smart Full HD 4K 32"',
    precio: 6499
  },
];

const teclados = [{
    nombre: 'Teclado Razer Ornata V3 X Alambrico de Membrana',
    precio: 499
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado HyperX Alloy Core RGB Gaming Alambrico',
    precio: 459
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado inalámbrico USB 850 (Color Negro)',
    precio: 249
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Teclado Primus Darth Vader Ballista90T Alambrico',
    precio: 500
  },
];

const mouses = [{
    nombre: 'Mouse Inalambrico Logitech M170 con Receptor USB',
    precio: 109
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme KMW-375BK Lightflex Inalambrico Plegable',
    precio: 119
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Klip Xtreme Vector Óptico Inalámbrico con 6 botones',
    precio: 79
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Mouse Gamer Corsair M65 RGB Elite Tunable FPS Negro CH-93099011',
    precio: 450
  },
];

const servidores = [{
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge T150 Procesador Intel Xeon E-2300 3.1Ghz 16GB de RAM ECC DDR4 1 TB HDD',
    precio: 9274
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Servidor Dell PowerEdge R450 Silver 4314 2.4Ghz 16GB DDR4-ECC 2TB PROSUPPPORTMISSION SIN DVD',
    precio: 39032
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Windows Server Standard 2022 64 bits Español DVD 16Core P73-08338',
    precio: 7412
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Switch Intellinet 561068 de 16 puertos 10/100/1000 Rackmount',
    precio: 635
  },
];

const electronicosTotales = [monitores, teclados, mouses, servidores];
//console.log(electronicosTotales)

precios = electronicosTotales.map(itemsArray =>{
  return itemsArray.map(item => {
    //console.log(item.precio)
    return item.precio;
  })
})

console.log(precios)




Claro, talvez no lo especifiqué pero exactamente para eso es; para filtrar datos por una condición dada.
Por ejemplo, yo lo que quiero hacer es recorrer el array anidado y filtrar por los elementos que sean menores a 500, y que eso lo muestre en pantalla.
Entonces esa sería realmente la duda, muchas gracias!

@AlexYeeze eso no aparecía en la redacción de la pregunta, ni en el código. Revisa el nuevo código, al inicio de la respuesta.
